# When does a short exact sequence of representations exist?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, homological-algebra

The context for this question is that I am trying to determine the Grothendieck group of finite-dimensional complex representations of $T = (\mathbb{C}^*)^n$, where $\mathbb{C}^*$ denotes the multiplicative group of complex numbers.

I would like a push toward the answer to this question: let $G$ be a group. Let $\rho:G\to GL(V)$, $\pi: G \to GL(W)$, and $\sigma: G\to GL(U)$ be three finite-dimensional representations, and consider the (not necessarily commutative) diagram of vector spaces and vector space homomorphisms

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> U @>{\alpha}>> V @>{\beta}>> W @>>> 0\\
\ @V{\sigma_g}VV @V{\rho_g}VV @V{\pi_g}VV \\
0 @>>> U @>{\alpha}>> V @>{\beta}>> W @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
What are necessary and/or sufficient conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the above diagram commutes for all $g\in G$ and the rows are exact? If there is no result leading toward an answer for general groups $G$, then what about when $G=T$?

Relevant: the finite-dimensional representations of $T$ factor into representations of the form $\mathbb{C}_{A_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{C}_{A_m}$, $A_i = (a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, where $\mathbb{C}_{A_i}$ is the one-dimensional representation given by the linear action $$T\times \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}: t.z = t_1^{a_1}t_2^{a_2}\cdots t_n^{a_n} z.$$

I saw that if either row is exact then the other is automatically exact, and that both rows must split since we're working in finite-dimensional vector spaces, so $\dim U + \dim W = \dim V$. Otherwise I'm not sure how to proceed - I'm a beginner when it comes to this sort of algebra.

Comment: Focus on T (you are not going to be able to say anything in the general case) Since you know all the finite dimensional representations,  you can simply look for all short exact sequences!

Comment: But how do I know which short exact sequences make the diagram commute? Or perhaps a better, smaller question, how do I know which $\alpha$ make the left square commute?

Comment: Consider two representations,  each with its decomoosition as a direct sum of 1-dimensional subrepresentations. Find all morphisms of representations betweem them.

Comment: This is what I see so far: $\sigma_t$ and $\rho_t$ can be thought of as diagonal matrices for each $t\in T$. We are looking for commutativity of matrices $\rho_t\alpha = \alpha\sigma_t$. $\rho_t$ multiplies each row of $\alpha$ by some $\prod t_i^{a_i}$, and $\sigma_t$ multiplies each column of $\alpha$ by some $\prod t_i^{b_i}$. Having different $a_i$-s and $b_i$-s means that the rows and columns vary at different rates as I vary $t$, unless (a tentative conjecture) the rows or columns of $\alpha$ are unit vectors, or zero. Does that sound close to right?

Comment: Your representations $\mathbb C_{A}$ are simple. Do you know about Schur's lemma?

Comment: I looked it up just now. I'm considering restricting $\beta$ to each direct summand of $V$. This produces a morphism of one-dimensional representations, which are irreducibles, so the restriction of $\beta$ is zero on $m=\dim U$ summands and isomorphism on $n=\dim W$ summands. $\alpha$ is an isomorphism onto its image, so by exactness $\alpha$ sends $U$ into the $m$ summands forming the kernel of $\beta$. Restricting $\alpha$ to each summand of $U$ produces isomorphisms of one-dimensional representations, so $\rho$ is a direct sum of $\sigma$ and another representation.

Comment: To produce the other representation, if we restrict $\beta$ to the direct summands of $V$ not in the kernel of $\beta$ this is a $n$-dimensional vector space, and $\beta$ maps it onto $W$, so the restriction of $\beta$ is an isomorphism. Restricting $\beta$ to the individual one-dimensional factors now produces (like for $\alpha$) isomorphisms of one-dimensional representations. All in all, we can conclude that $\rho = \sigma\oplus\pi$. I've left out some minor details, but is this what you're driving at?

Comment: All right, I've worked out the details and I think this is the correct proof! If you can post your comment about Schur's lemma as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as an answer, since that was really the hint that got me past this roadblock.

Comment: It is best if you yourself post the complete answer!

Comment: I'll post a complete answer as well, but I want to give credit where it's due.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer to my question. Thanks to Mariano Suarez-Alvarez for reminding me about Schur's lemma.

First, let us identify $U = \mathbb{C}^m$, $V = \mathbb{C}^{n+m}$, $W = \mathbb{C}^n$.

The decomposition of $\rho$ into irreducible representations $\rho = \mathbb{C}_{b_1}\oplus\cdots\mathbb{C}_{b_{n+m}}$ produces a decomposition of $\mathbb{C}$ into $n+m$ copies of $\mathbb{C}$. Consider the restriction of $\beta$ to one of those factors: we have the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{C} @>{\beta}>> \beta(\mathbb{C}) \\
 @V{\mathbb{C}_{b_i}}VV @VV{\psi_t\mid_{\beta(\mathbb{C})}}V \\
\mathbb{C} @>{\beta}>> \beta(\mathbb{C})
\end{CD}
$$
Since $\beta(\mathbb{C})$ has dimension at most $1$, the restriction of $\psi_t$ is either a zero-dimensional or one-dimensional representation. The zero-dimensional representation is uninteresting, so suppose the restriction is a one-dimensional representation; the decomposition of representations into irreducibles implies that this is an irreducible representation. By Schur's lemma, $\beta$ restricted to this direct summand $\mathbb{C}$ must be zero or an isomorphism. Since $\beta$ is onto, this implies that $\beta$ sends $n$ summands injectively into $W = \mathbb{C}^n$, and the remaining $m$ summands are exactly $\ker\beta = \text{im}~\alpha$.

Consider the restriction of $\alpha$ to its direct summands as before. $\alpha$ is an isomorphism onto its image, so this produces isomorphisms of irreducible representations
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{C} @>{\alpha}>> \alpha(\mathbb{C}) \\
 @V{\mathbb{C}_{a_j}}VV @VV{\rho_t\mid_{\alpha(\mathbb{C})}}V \\
\mathbb{C} @>{\alpha}>> \alpha(\mathbb{C})
\end{CD}
$$
So the representation $(V,\rho)$ breaks up into representations $V = \text{im}~\alpha\oplus \beta^{-1}(\mathbb{C}^{n}) = \mathbb{C}^m\oplus\mathbb{C}^n$, and $\rho = \sigma\oplus\pi$, where $\sigma$ is regarded as a representation $\text{im}~\alpha\to\text{im}~\alpha$ and $\pi$ as a representation $\beta^{-1}(\mathbb{C}^n)\to\beta^{-1}(\mathbb{C}^n)$; this is possible because we have shown that $\sigma$ and $\pi$ are isomorphic to such representations via the above diagrams.

This is also obviously a sufficient condition, so we conclude that a short exact sequence of representations $0\to\sigma\to\rho\to\pi\to 0$ exists if and only if $\rho \cong\sigma\oplus\pi$.